# SVG image not getting passed to a function in an onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an svg that has an `onclick` event but whenever it is clicked the `event.target` is a `path` that has been clicked not the whole `svg`, why is that? Is this how svg's work? Here is my code.

**In my Js I `console.log()` the svg when ever it is clicked, you can inspect that but what you get isnt the whole svg rather the path (some part) that has been clicked**

```js
let svg = document.body.querySelector('.notebook');
svg.addEventListener("click",openHome)
let div2 = document.body.querySelector('.div2')
function openHome(event){
  console.log(event.target)
  div2.innerText= event.target;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <head>
  <body>
                
<svg class="notebook"
                        
fill="none" viewBox="0 0 176 227" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g clip-path="url(#a)">
<path d="m173.58 0.18188h-162.68v226.21h162.68c0.585 0 1.145-0.232 1.558-0.645 0.414-0.413 0.646-0.974 0.646-1.558v-221.8c0-0.58435-0.232-1.1448-0.646-1.558-0.413-0.4132-0.973-0.64534-1.558-0.64535zm-153.5 219.96c-0.7989 0-1.5799-0.237-2.2441-0.68-0.6643-0.444-1.1821-1.075-1.4878-1.813s-0.3857-1.55-0.2299-2.334c0.1559-0.784 0.5406-1.503 1.1055-2.068 0.565-0.565 1.2847-0.95 2.0683-1.106s1.5958-0.076 2.3339 0.23 1.3689 0.824 1.8128 1.488 0.6808 1.445 0.6808 2.244c0 0.53-0.1045 1.056-0.3075 1.546s-0.5006 0.935-0.8756 1.31c-0.3751 0.375-0.8204 0.673-1.3105 0.876s-1.0154 0.307-1.5459 0.307zm0-20.564c-0.7989 0-1.5798-0.237-2.2441-0.681s-1.182-1.074-1.4878-1.812c-0.3057-0.739-0.3857-1.551-0.2298-2.334 0.1558-0.784 0.5405-1.504 1.1055-2.069 0.5649-0.565 1.2846-0.949 2.0682-1.105s1.5958-0.076 2.3339 0.23 1.3689 0.823 1.8128 1.488c0.4439 0.664 0.6808 1.445 0.6808 2.244 0 0.53-0.1045 1.055-0.3075 1.546-0.203 0.49-0.5005 0.935-0.8756 1.31s-0.8204 0.673-1.3105 0.876-1.0154 0.307-1.5459 0.307zm0-20.564c-0.7989 0-1.5798-0.237-2.2441-0.681s-1.182-1.075-1.4878-1.813c-0.3057-0.738-0.3857-1.55-0.2298-2.334 0.1558-0.783 0.5405-1.503 1.1055-2.068 0.5649-0.565 1.2846-0.95 2.0682-1.105 0.7836-0.156 1.5958-0.076 2.3339 0.229 0.7381 0.306 1.3689 0.824 1.8128 1.488 0.4439 0.665 0.6808 1.445 0.6808 2.244 0 0.531-0.1045 1.056-0.3075 1.546s-0.5006 0.936-0.8756 1.311c-0.3751 0.375-0.8204 0.672-1.3105 0.875s-1.0154 0.308-1.5459 0.308zm0-20.564c-0.7989 0-1.5798-0.237-2.2441-0.681s-1.182-1.075-1.4878-1.813c-0.3057-0.738-0.3857-1.55-0.2298-2.334 0.1558-0.784 0.5405-1.503 1.1055-2.068 0.5649-0.565 1.2846-0.95 2.0682-1.106s1.5958-0.076 2.3339 0.23 1.3689 0.824 1.8128 1.488 0.6808 1.445 0.6808 2.244c0 0.531-0.1045 1.056-0.3075 1.546s-0.5006 0.935-0.8756 1.31c-0.3751 0.375-0.8204 0.673-1.3105 0.876s-1.0154 0.308-1.5459 0.308zm0-20.565c-0.7989 0-1.5798-0.237-2.2441-0.681-0.6643-0.443-1.182-1.074-1.4878-1.812-0.3057-0.738-0.3857-1.551-0.2298-2.334 0.1558-0.784 0.5405-1.504 1.1055-2.068 0.5649-0.565 1.2846-0.95 2.0682-1.106s1.5958-0.076 2.3339 0.23 1.3689 0.823 1.8128 1.488c0.4439 0.664 0.6808 1.445 0.6808 2.244 0 0.53-0.1045 1.056-0.3075 1.546s-0.5006 0.935-0.8756 1.31c-0.3751 0.375-0.8204 0.673-1.3105 0.876s-1.0154 0.307-1.5459 0.307zm0-20.564c-0.7989 0-1.5798-0.237-2.2441-0.681s-1.182-1.075-1.4878-1.813c-0.3057-0.738-0.3857-1.55-0.2298-2.334 0.1558-0.783 0.5405-1.503 1.1055-2.068 0.5649-0.565 1.2846-0.949 2.0682-1.105s1.5958-0.076 2.3339 0.23c0.7381 0.305 1.3689 0.823 1.8128 1.487 0.4439 0.665 0.6808 1.446 0.6808 2.245 0 0.53-0.1045 1.055-0.3075 1.545s-0.5006 0.936-0.8756 1.311c-0.3751 0.375-0.8204 0.672-1.3105 0.875s-1.0154 0.308-1.5459 0.308zm0-20.564c-0.7989 0-1.5798-0.2369-2.2441-0.6807-0.6643-0.4439-1.182-1.0748-1.4878-1.8129-0.3057-0.7381-0.3857-1.5503-0.2298-2.3338 0.1558-0.7836 0.5405-1.5034 1.1055-2.0683 0.5649-0.5649 1.2846-0.9496 2.0682-1.1055 0.7836-0.1558 1.5958-0.0758 2.3339 0.2299s1.3689 0.8234 1.8128 1.4877 0.6808 1.4453 0.6808 2.2442c0 0.5305-0.1045 1.0557-0.3075 1.5458s-0.5006 0.9354-0.8756 1.3105c-0.3751 0.3751-0.8204 0.6726-1.3105 0.8756s-1.0154 0.3075-1.5459 0.3075zm0-20.564c-0.7989 0-1.5798-0.2369-2.2441-0.6807-0.6643-0.4439-1.182-1.0748-1.4878-1.8129-0.3057-0.7381-0.3857-1.5503-0.2298-2.3338 0.1558-0.7836 0.5405-1.5034 1.1055-2.0683 0.5649-0.5649 1.2846-0.9496 2.0682-1.1055 0.7836-0.1558 1.5958-0.0758 2.3339 0.2299s1.3689 0.8235 1.8128 1.4877c0.4439 0.6643 0.6808 1.4453 0.6808 2.2442 0 0.5305-0.1045 1.0558-0.3075 1.5458-0.203 0.4901-0.5006 0.9354-0.8756 1.3105-0.3751 0.3751-0.8204 0.6727-1.3105 0.8757s-1.0154 0.3074-1.5459 0.3074zm0-20.564c-0.7989 0-1.5798-0.2369-2.2441-0.6807-0.6643-0.4439-1.182-1.0748-1.4878-1.8129-0.3057-0.7381-0.3857-1.5503-0.2298-2.3338 0.1558-0.7836 0.5405-1.5034 1.1055-2.0683 0.5649-0.5649 1.2846-0.9496 2.0682-1.1055 0.7836-0.1558 1.5958-0.0758 2.3339 0.2299s1.3689 0.8235 1.8128 1.4878c0.4439 0.6642 0.6808 1.4452 0.6808 2.2441 0 0.5305-0.1045 1.0558-0.3075 1.5458-0.203 0.4901-0.5006 0.9354-0.8756 1.3105-0.3751 0.3751-0.8204 0.6727-1.3105 0.8757s-1.0154 0.3074-1.5459 0.3074zm0-20.564c-0.7989 0-1.5799-0.2369-2.2441-0.6807-0.6643-0.4439-1.1821-1.0747-1.4878-1.8129-0.3057-0.7381-0.3857-1.5502-0.2299-2.3338 0.1559-0.7836 0.5406-1.5034 1.1055-2.0683 0.565-0.5649 1.2847-0.9496 2.0683-1.1055 0.7836-0.1558 1.5958-0.0759 2.3339 0.2299 0.7381 0.3057 1.3689 0.8235 1.8128 1.4877 0.4439 0.6643 0.6808 1.4453 0.6808 2.2442 0 0.5305-0.1045 1.0558-0.3075 1.5458-0.203 0.4901-0.5006 0.9354-0.8756 1.3105-0.3751 0.3751-0.8204 0.6727-1.3105 0.8757s-1.0154 0.3074-1.5459 0.3074zm0-20.564c-0.7989 1e-4 -1.5799-0.2369-2.2441-0.6807-0.6643-0.4439-1.1821-1.0747-1.4878-1.8128s-0.3857-1.5503-0.2299-2.3339c0.1559-0.78357 0.5406-1.5033 1.1055-2.0682 0.565-0.56493 1.2847-0.94965 2.0683-1.1055s1.5958-0.07587 2.3339 0.22986c0.7381 0.30574 1.3689 0.82348 1.8128 1.4878s0.6808 1.4453 0.6808 2.2442c0 0.5305-0.1045 1.0558-0.3075 1.5458-0.203 0.4901-0.5006 0.9354-0.8756 1.3105-0.3751 0.3751-0.8204 0.6727-1.3105 0.8757s-1.0154 0.3075-1.5459 0.3074z" fill="#3F3D56"/>
<path d="m10.901 12.667c-1.09 0-10.649-0.0515-10.649-1.8361 0-1.7846 9.5594-1.8361 10.649-1.8361v0.73444c-5.6304 0-9.2812 0.63024-9.8692 1.1016 0.58794 0.4714 4.2388 1.1017 9.8692 1.1017 5.6178 0 9.2648-0.6276 9.865-1.0984-0.2856-0.2018-1.4525-0.6246-4.5823-0.89514l0.0632-0.73157c5.3034 0.4583 5.3034 1.3048 5.3034 1.6234 0 1.7846-9.5593 1.8361-10.649 1.8361z" fill="#2F2E41"/>
<path d="m10.901 32.865c-1.09 0-10.649-0.0515-10.649-1.8361 0-1.7847 9.5594-1.8361 10.649-1.8361v0.7344c-5.6303 0-9.2811 0.6303-9.8691 1.1017 0.58794 0.4714 4.2388 1.1017 9.8691 1.1017 5.6178 0 9.2649-0.6276 9.8651-1.0985-0.2857-0.2017-1.4525-0.6245-4.5823-0.8951l0.0632-0.7315c5.3034 0.4583 5.3034 1.3048 5.3034 1.6234 0 1.7846-9.5594 1.8361-10.649 1.8361z" fill="#2F2E41"/>
<path d="m10.901 53.429c-1.09 0-10.649-0.0514-10.649-1.8361s9.5594-1.8361 10.649-1.8361v0.7344c-5.6304 0-9.2812 0.6303-9.8692 1.1017 0.58794 0.4714 4.2388 1.1017 9.8692 1.1017 5.6178 0 9.2648-0.6276 9.865-1.0985-0.2856-0.2017-1.4525-0.6245-4.5823-0.8951l0.0632-0.7315c5.3034 0.4583 5.3034 1.3048 5.3034 1.6234 0 1.7847-9.5593 1.8361-10.649 1.8361z" fill="#2F2E41"/>
<path d="m10.901 73.993c-1.09 0-10.649-0.0515-10.649-1.8362 0-1.7846 9.5594-1.8361 10.649-1.8361v0.7345c-5.6303 0-9.2811 0.6302-9.8691 1.1016 0.58794 0.4715 4.2388 1.1017 9.8691 1.1017 5.6178 0 9.2649-0.6276 9.8651-1.0984-0.2857-0.2017-1.4525-0.6246-4.5823-0.8951l0.0632-0.7316c5.3034 0.4583 5.3034 1.3048 5.3034 1.6235 0 1.7846-9.5594 1.8361-10.649 1.8361z" fill="#2F2E41"/>
<path d="m10.901 94.558c-1.09 0-10.649-0.0515-10.649-1.8361 0-1.7847 9.5594-1.8361 10.649-1.8361v0.7344c-5.6304 0-9.2812 0.6303-9.8692 1.1017 0.58794 0.4714 4.2388 1.1016 9.8692 1.1016 5.6178 0 9.2648-0.6276 9.8651-1.0984-0.2857-0.2017-1.4526-0.6245-4.5824-0.8951l0.0632-0.7316c5.3034 0.4583 5.3034 1.3048 5.3034 1.6235 0 1.7846-9.5593 1.8361-10.649 1.8361z" fill="#2F2E41"/>
<path d="m10.901 115.12c-1.09 0-10.649-0.052-10.649-1.836 0-1.785 9.5594-1.837 10.649-1.837v0.735c-5.6304 0-9.2812 0.63-9.8692 1.102 0.58794 0.471 4.2388 1.101 9.8692 1.101 5.6178 0 9.2648-0.627 9.865-1.098-0.2856-0.202-1.4525-0.625-4.5823-0.895l0.0632-0.732c5.3034 0.458 5.3034 1.305 5.3034 1.624 0 1.784-9.5593 1.836-10.649 1.836z" fill="#2F2E41"/>
<path d="m10.901 135.69c-1.09 0-10.649-0.052-10.649-1.836 0-1.785 9.5594-1.836 10.649-1.836v0.734c-5.6304 0-9.2812 0.63-9.8692 1.102 0.58794 0.471 4.2388 1.101 9.8692 1.101 5.6178 0 9.2648-0.627 9.865-1.098-0.2856-0.202-1.4525-0.625-4.5823-0.895l0.0632-0.732c5.3034 0.459 5.3034 1.305 5.3034 1.624 0 1.784-9.5593 1.836-10.649 1.836z" fill="#2F2E41"/>
<path d="m10.901 156.25c-1.09 0-10.649-0.051-10.649-1.836 0-1.784 9.5594-1.836 10.649-1.836v0.735c-5.6304 0-9.2812 0.63-9.8692 1.101 0.58795 0.472 4.2388 1.102 9.8692 1.102 5.6178 0 9.2648-0.628 9.8651-1.099-0.2857-0.201-1.4525-0.624-4.5824-0.895l0.0632-0.731c5.3035 0.458 5.3035 1.305 5.3035 1.623 0 1.785-9.5594 1.836-10.649 1.836z" fill="#2F2E41"/>
<path d="m10.901 176.82c-1.09 0-10.649-0.052-10.649-1.837 0-1.784 9.5594-1.836 10.649-1.836v0.735c-5.6304 0-9.2812 0.63-9.8692 1.101 0.58794 0.472 4.2388 1.102 9.8692 1.102 5.6178 0 9.2648-0.628 9.865-1.098-0.2856-0.202-1.4525-0.625-4.5823-0.895l0.0632-0.732c5.3034 0.458 5.3034 1.305 5.3034 1.623 0 1.785-9.5593 1.837-10.649 1.837z" fill="#2F2E41"/>
<path d="m10.901 197.38c-1.09 0-10.649-0.052-10.649-1.836 0-1.785 9.5594-1.836 10.649-1.836v0.734c-5.6304 0-9.2812 0.63-9.8692 1.102 0.58794 0.471 4.2388 1.101 9.8692 1.101 5.6178 0 9.2648-0.627 9.8651-1.098-0.2857-0.202-1.4526-0.624-4.5824-0.895l0.0632-0.732c5.3034 0.459 5.3034 1.305 5.3034 1.624 0 1.784-9.5593 1.836-10.649 1.836z" fill="#2F2E41"/>
<path d="m10.901 217.94c-1.09 0-10.649-0.052-10.649-1.836 0-1.785 9.5594-1.836 10.649-1.836v0.734c-5.6304 0-9.2812 0.63-9.8692 1.102 0.58794 0.471 4.2388 1.101 9.8692 1.101 5.6178 0 9.2648-0.627 9.865-1.098-0.2856-0.202-1.4525-0.624-4.5823-0.895l0.0632-0.732c5.3034 0.459 5.3034 1.305 5.3034 1.624 0 1.784-9.5593 1.836-10.649 1.836z" fill="#2F2E41"/>
<path d="m141.33 71.242h-87.765c-0.6875-4e-4 -1.3465-0.1453-1.8327-0.403-0.4861-0.2577-0.7595-0.607-0.7603-0.9714v-18.185c8e-4 -0.3645 0.2742-0.7138 0.7603-0.9715 0.4862-0.2577 1.1452-0.4026 1.8327-0.403h87.765c0.688 4e-4 1.347 0.1453 1.833 0.403s0.76 0.607 0.76 0.9715v18.185c0 0.3644-0.274 0.7137-0.76 0.9714s-1.145 0.4026-1.833 0.403z" fill="#fff"/>
<g clip-path="url(#clip1)">
<path d="m150.92 159.82c0.01 7.675-1.544 15.272-4.566 22.327l-0.188 0.432c-5.113 11.632-13.978 21.212-25.178 27.211-11.201 5.998-24.089 8.067-36.604 5.877-0.3406-0.061-0.6805-0.123-1.0199-0.188-3.507-0.68-6.9411-1.693-10.256-3.025-0.5384-0.216-1.073-0.44-1.6036-0.672-0.3623-0.158-0.7246-0.321-1.0836-0.488-9.8198-4.551-18.134-11.815-23.962-20.935s-8.9281-19.716-8.9339-30.539c0-31.313 25.385-56.697 56.697-56.697 31.313 0 56.698 25.384 56.698 56.697z" fill="#2F2E41"/>
<path d="m84.379 215.66c-0.3405-0.061-0.6805-0.123-1.0199-0.188-0.2214-6.426-0.9813-19.616-3.5729-33.43-1.4175-7.56-3.3851-15.31-6.1143-22.237-0.935-2.397-2.0029-4.741-3.1989-7.019-2.7577-5.208-6.1025-9.593-10.158-12.564l0.5972-0.815c3.3733 2.473 6.405 5.944 9.095 10.414 0.8069 1.338 1.5818 2.766 2.3249 4.284 0.7968 1.624 1.5567 3.347 2.2797 5.171 0.4613 1.161 0.9069 2.362 1.3369 3.603 1.872 5.39 3.4633 11.539 4.774 18.449 0.2902 1.526 0.5664 3.09 0.8286 4.692 2.0314 12.408 2.6437 23.879 2.8282 29.64z" fill="#07C5AE" opacity=".2"/>
<path d="m71.5 211.78c-0.3623-0.158-0.7247-0.321-1.0836-0.488-0.3506-3.808-0.9947-8.532-2.1723-13.016-0.5158-2.013-1.1779-3.987-1.9811-5.904-1.3436-3.145-3.0831-5.819-5.3326-7.468l0.5972-0.814c2.3551 1.725 4.1718 4.451 5.5758 7.639 1.5819 3.593 2.637 7.775 3.3398 11.771 0.5217 2.967 0.8505 5.834 1.0568 8.28z" fill="#07C5AE" opacity=".2"/>
<path d="m54.674 140.2c2.7874 0 5.0471-2.26 5.0471-5.047 0-2.788-2.2597-5.047-5.0471-5.047-2.7875 0-5.0472 2.259-5.0472 5.047 0 2.787 2.2597 5.047 5.0472 5.047z" fill="#07C5AE" opacity=".2"/>
<path d="m56.299 183.65c2.7875 0 5.0472-2.26 5.0472-5.047 0-2.788-2.2597-5.047-5.0472-5.047-2.7874 0-5.0471 2.259-5.0471 5.047 0 2.787 2.2597 5.047 5.0471 5.047z" fill="#07C5AE" opacity=".2"/>
<path d="m74.711 143.63c-1.0702 6.039 1.2924 11.506 1.2924 11.506s4.098-4.322 5.1683-10.36c1.0702-6.039-1.2924-11.506-1.2924-11.506s-4.098 4.322-5.1683 10.36z" fill="#07C5AE" opacity=".2"/>
<path d="m57.937 157.97c5.7595 2.106 11.547 0.754 11.547 0.754s-3.5505-4.766-9.31-6.872-11.547-0.754-11.547-0.754 3.5505 4.766 9.3099 6.872z" fill="#07C5AE" opacity=".2"/>
<path d="m56.961 196.44c4.037 1.476 8.0992 0.513 8.0992 0.513s-2.4828-3.356-6.5198-4.832c-4.0369-1.477-8.0992-0.514-8.0992-0.514s2.4829 3.357 6.5198 4.833z" fill="#07C5AE" opacity=".2"/>
<path d="m94.101 172.37c12.207 0 22.104-9.896 22.104-22.104 0-12.207-9.897-22.103-22.104-22.103-12.208 0-22.104 9.896-22.104 22.103 0 12.208 9.8961 22.104 22.104 22.104z" fill="#A0616A"/>
<path d="m85.467 167.19s2.763 13.124 2.763 14.505c0 1.382 13.124 7.598 13.124 7.598l11.742-2.072 4.145-12.433s-6.908-10.361-6.908-14.506l-24.866 6.908z" fill="#A0616A"/>
<path d="m146.35 182.14-0.188 0.433c-5.113 11.631-13.978 21.212-25.178 27.21s-24.089 8.067-36.604 5.877c-0.3405-0.06-0.6804-0.123-1.0198-0.188-3.507-0.68-6.9412-1.693-10.256-3.024-0.5385-0.217-1.073-0.441-1.6036-0.673-0.3624-0.158-0.7247-0.32-1.0837-0.488-3.2537-1.508-6.3569-3.321-9.2678-5.415l-2.6201-7.6 1.4727-1.124 6.2619-4.781 0.8404-0.642 12.683-9.682 0.936-0.715 6.5923-5.032 0.0017-2e-3s7.1291 11.616 17.49 8.162c10.362-3.453 10.135-13.357 10.135-13.357l31.407 11.041z" fill="#3A3768"/>
<path d="m74.933 132.46s7.0179-15.205 20.469-11.697c13.45 3.509 21.054 8.773 21.638 14.036s-0.293 13.158-0.293 13.158-1.462-10.819-10.819-8.479c-9.3569 2.339-23.977 0.584-23.977 0.584l-2.3393 21.054s-2.6317-3.802-5.5558-1.462c-2.9241 2.339-8.4798-22.516 0.8772-27.194z" fill="#3A3768"/>
<path d="m73.104 212.45c-0.5384-0.216-1.073-0.44-1.6036-0.672-0.3623-0.158-0.7247-0.321-1.0836-0.488-5.3814-2.496-10.339-5.818-14.693-9.847 1.5416-2.1 2.8047-3.169 2.8047-3.169h10.362l1.5533 5.224 2.6604 8.952z" fill="#3A3768"/>
<path d="m137.27 181.01 8.889 1.57c-2.379 5.419-5.592 10.432-9.521 14.857l0.632-16.427z" fill="#3A3768"/>
</g>
</g>
<defs>
<clipPath id="a">
<rect width="176" height="227" fill="#fff"/>
</clipPath>
</defs>
</svg>
<div class="div2"></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

a code pen demo if you want https://codepen.io/hileamlak/pen/qBZVqaW.

So when a region in the svg is clicked here is what is console logged.
[image]
But I was expecting the whole svg to be printed

Comment: Is `let` global to functions? I havent tested, just wondering.

Comment: yes, I think so

Comment: Yeah agree with you, just tested, so something else. .... What is the kind of output you are getting? If you could post an example in your question, if possible

Comment: Actually whenever i click your svg (here) I get a script timeout. Could be some unforeseen recursion going on or otherwise buggy infinite loop in the engine. Likely the former.

Comment: See the answer by @gaetanoM below; it explains the recursive-like nature --- but due to bubbling because as stated there you have to use `this` for the svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. The `event.target` is the element, where the event was triggered. If a `path` is clicked, then `event.target` is the `path`. The event then bubbles up, until it reaches the `svg`, where it is listened. But the `event.target` remains the original element.

Have a look at [bubbling and capturing](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) or search elsewhere how event propagation works.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, event.target is the path on which you clicked, while **this** is the svg element:

```js
let svg = document.body.querySelector('.notebook');
svg.addEventListener("click",openHome)
let div2 = document.body.querySelector('.div2')
function openHome(event){
  console.log(event.target)
  div2.innerText= this.outerHTML;
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ey4fo7qg/4/)

Comment: so what does outerHTML do? and if you can can you inspect you fiddle demo and see what is printed with event.target, it isnt printing the whole svg (just the clicked path)? is it beacuse the onclick event is  inherted to the children of the svg and the paths are responding to that?

Comment: yes it is inherted .... but while **this** refers to the svg the event.target refers to the path on which you clicked